# measure the distance of transparent image to actual image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to measure the distance of the transparent boundary to the image (on y-axis):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.png')
im.show()
#im.size = (500,500) I assume the distance will be from 200-300
```

[image: Image 1]

Is there anyway to do this or get an estimate from the top point of purse to top of transparent image ?

Comment: Good question so far, but while writing an answer, I came across a problem:
Please define distance! There are many, like the distance to each of the four border, the minimum euclidean distance between the outer border and the non transparent pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image and ensure there is an alpha channel
im = Image.open('bag.png').convert('RGBA')

# Get the alpha channel
alpha = im.getchannel('A')

# Get the bounding box
bbox = alpha.getbbox()           # Result is the bounding box (87, 221, 473, 463)
```

**Edited image for testing:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy to manipulate you image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.png')

#split image
r, g, b, a = np.array(img)[:,:,0], np.array(img)[:,:,1], np.array(img)[:,:,2], np.array(img)[:,:,3]
idx, idy = np.where(a>0)

# distance to borders (left, right, top, bottom)
distx = (idx.min(), a.shape[0] - idx.max())
disty = (idy.min(), a.shape[1] - idy.max())
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally with PNG images you have 4 channels in an image. The first 3 channels are representative of the RGB channels and the fourth channel, the alpha channel, represents the transparency value for each channel, where 0 is completely invisible and 1 is completely visible. What you can do is you can cycle through the alpha channel and check the first pixel that has the alpha channel not equal to 0, you will then get what you are looking for

Comment: *"cycling through"* an image (with `for` loops) is generally to be avoided in Python.

Comment: it can be done  without cycling through as well, just create an array of 1s, np.ones((img_h,img_W)) an multiply with the alpha channel, it will give you a mask. Just find its bounding rect and u have the points

Comment: or simply, i, j = np.where(alpha_channel > 0), and take the first element